# java: open-source APM (application performance management)

Tags: java, open-source, apm

I am looking for an open-source application/tool/technology which can show times of distributed request across distributed system.

I have found some wonderful stuff like [AppDynamics](http://www.appdynamics.com/), but they are all commercial. I don't need such a wide functionality, but simple request tracking. I have also had a look on [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software), but I have some difficulties to understand it.

Could you recommend some solutions if you are experienced with APM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't think that you can do full-featured profiling of distributed request across number of JVM's - AppDynamics from what i can remember understands the EE stuff - like calling DB, EJB, RMI, or remote webservice - however it still works in scope of JVM.

Isn't it suffient in your case just to use java profiler (like yourkit, jprofiler)?

Comment: I need information like this:
`request124:
component1-436ms
component2-36ms
component5-4336ms
component4-4ms`
Is it possible to get it using yourkit/jprofiler?

Comment: sure you will get the full nested stacktrace of method's execution. yourkit supports both sampling and tracing http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/cpu_intro.jsp

Comment: also if you need really monitoring tool rather than profiling, take a look into Jboss monitoring tools - they are pretty good and free

Comment: @AndreyBorisow That sounds great! If I have understood correctly I can get "full nested stacktrace of method's execution" even if there are proceed on different JVMs. Is that true?

Comment: you will see that communication request (RMI call), socket read-write took for example 15 milliseconds

Comment: Great! And can I go further? for example thread in LoggingComponent starts second thread in AuthenticationComponent. After authentication request goes to third thread in CalculationConent on a different JVM, and so on. Or does it check only time of connection between two components? Which of things you mensioned should I use then?  yourkit/jprofiler/jboss? Thaks a lot for your help!

Comment: use yourkit, this will give you information of all thread, all method executions.

Comment: I contacted with YourKit technical support. I also realized it is not an open-source (free licence is granted to developers of non-commercial Open Source projects). You seem to have great knowledge about APMs, could you recommend some free solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the free version of AppDynamics. It's called AppDynamics LITE.
You can take a look also to EXTRAHOP free version. Maybe it is good enough for your needs.

Also you can try using a SaaS solutions such as NewRelic or Boundary. They have free accounts that could also be good enough for your needs.

Finally if you want to monitor the performance of any specific JAVA application, you can use http://www.moskito.org/. It's totaly FREE.

Answer (score 1):

you can try 24x7monitoring

https://code.google.com/p/monitor-24x7/

it provides method level monitoring, SQL queries, business transactions...